# Hyphothesis test for a coin tossed 10000 times

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

For a coin, there is no information whether it is fair or not. The following two hypothesis
are supposed for getting tail : $H_0 : p = 0,5$ and $H_1 : p = 0,7$. This coin is tossed $10^4$
times and if the number of tails that appeared at the top is more than $4940$, $H_0$ is accepted. Find  $\alpha $(type 1 error).

I do not understand why $H_0 $ is accepted,since we are in the non-critical region,then we can easily find $\beta$ but not $\alpha$

$\alpha=P(H_1:\text{accepted}|H_0 : true)=\frac{P(H_1\cap H_0)}{P(H_0:\text{true})}$

$P(H_0:\text{true})=\frac{4940}{10000}=0.494$ 
i dont know how to proceed from here...

Comment: I believe the $104$ times tossed should be $10^4$ times to match the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The test statistic that you wrote is not consistent with the hypotheses you stated.  If $H_0 : p = 0.5$ and $H_1 : p = 0.7$, and $p$ is the single trial probability of flipping a **tail**, then the test should **reject** $H_0$ if more than a certain number of tails are observed.  What you have written is that $H_0$ is accepted if more than $4940$ tails are observed.

Okay, so say I take your question exactly as it is stated.  Then your type I error is the conditional probability of rejecting $H_0$ when $H_0$ is true; i.e., $p = 0.5$ but you observed more than $4940$ tails out of $10^4$ trials.  This is a binomial probability with $n = 10^4$, $p = 0.5$:  $$\alpha = \sum_{x=4941}^{10000} \binom{10000}{x} (0.5)^x (1 - 0.5)^{10000-x}.$$  Of course, we can approximate this sum using a normal approximation:  the binomial distribution can be approximated with a normal distribution with mean $np = 5000$ and variance $np(1-p) = 2500$, so $$\alpha \approx \Pr[4940.5 \le X] = \Pr[-1.19 \le Z] = 0.882977.$$  This is your probability of Type I error given the **EXACT** statement of your question.  But as I said earlier, this makes no sense because your test statistic is not consistent with your hypotheses.  You are basically saying that the more tails you observe, the more likely you will conclude the coin is fair.  That is why the Type I error we calculated above is so large.

Comment: this is very helpful,i believe the question was supposed to make $H_1$ accepted which will agree with the evaluation of α,will this change our binomial probabilty approaximation above :-

"if the number of tails that appeared at the top is more than 4940, $H_1$ is accepted"

Comment: In that case, the Type I error is simply $1 - 0.882977$, since the decision to reject $H_0$ and the decision not to reject $H_0$, given that $H_0$ is true, are complementary events.

Comment: okay i see it,the correct decision is not rejecting $H_0$ ,since it is giving the minimum error$\alpha=0.117023$,i am also now concerned in $beta$ ,so if i am concerned in finding $\beta$ i will just plug $p=0.7$ in the place of $0.5$?

Comment: Beta is the probability of Type II error, which is the probability of failing to reject $H_0$ when $H_1$ is true.  In this case, you simply compute the probability of observing no more than 4940 tails if the true value of $p$ is $0.7$.

Comment: thanks a lot this has been helpful...i understand completely ,this solution is sufficient.